# How do I exclude search results in Python

Tags: python

I am using the following library to extract google search urls:

```
from googlesearch import search
```

This is the function that performs the google search:

```
search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=None, pause=2.0)
```

My question is: How do I use this function to exclude certain domains in my search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use search interface to exclude a domain, add an argument

```
 extra_params={'-site' : 'youtube.com'}
```

e.g.

```
  search(query,
      tld='com',
      lang='en',
      num=10,
      start=0,
      stop=None,
      pause=2.0,
      extra_params={'-site' : 'youtube.com'}
  )
```

Alternatively, you can just append `-site:youtube.com` or whatever needed into your query.

Comment: I put this inside the query argument of search?

Comment: yes, you can just include -site:xxxx.yyy into your query

Comment: ohh I see, thank you. What if I want to include only certain country domain names inside my search. Like for example, I only want .uk domains.

Comment: for inclusion there is specialized argument `domains=['uk', 'org', 'fr']` (or add site:uk to the query)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help